# why my Linqued query not working?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this sql query which works fine

```
    select u.FirstName,u.LastName,case when ei.Gender=1 then 'Male' else 'Female' end as Gender,t.Name as 'Team Name',ei.MobileNumber,u.Phone as 'Alternative Number',u.EmailAddress,ei.AlternateEmailAddress,ei.GMail,ei.Skype,FORMAT(ei.DateOfBirth,'dd-MMM-yyyy') AS BirthDay,ei.Address1,ei.Address2,ei.City,ei.[State],ei.Country,ei.ZipPostalCode,ei.Designation,ei.MasterLeaves
 from Employee e
inner join [user] u
on e.[User]=u.Id and IsDeleted!=1
inner join Team t 
on e.Team=t.Id
inner join EmployeeInformation ei
on e.AdditionalInformation=ei.Id
```

when 
I converted the same query to linqued query i.e

```
    var EmpReport = (from Emp in db.Employees
                 join Usr in db.Users
                 on Emp.User equals Usr.Id
                 join Tm in db.Teams
                on Emp.Team equals Tm.Id
                 join Ei in db.EmployeeInformations
                 on Emp.AdditionalInformation equals Ei.Id
                 where Usr.IsDeleted  != true
                select new { Usr.FirstName, Usr.LastName, Gender = Ei.Gender == 1 ? "Male" : "Female", Team_Name = Tm.Name, Ei.MobileNumber, Alternative_Number = Usr.Phone, Email_Address = Usr.EmailAddress, Alternate_Email_Address = Ei.AlternateEmailAddress, Ei.GMail, Ei.Skype, Birthday = Ei.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), Ei.Address1, Ei.Address2, Ei.State, Ei.Country, Ei.ZipPostalCode, Ei.Designation, Ei.MasterLeaves }).ToList();
```

it gave me this error

```
 LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
     'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot
      be translated into a store expression.
```

The Error is basically causing in this part

```
Birthday = Ei.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy").
```

where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error because `DateTime.ToString()` is a .NET function and not directly translateable to SQL. Either return your `DateOfBirth` column in its native format and change the format once you have your results in your app, or use some of the SQL functions available in Linq-to-Entities, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16364484/5785878